# Trim FIRST character in string that has multiple text of that character

Tags: sql, sql-server, character, trim

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I'm trying to trim values that looks like this

```
DocID
----------------    
FOO_1_23_456
FOO1_1_23_4567
```

I'm trying to make it so it will only give me everything after the first '_'

Result

```
 _1_23_456
 _1_23_4567
```

Right now my query is

```
select 
    right(DocIDDocument, LEN(DocID.Document) - 3)) AS NewDocID
```

which only the trims the first 3 characters, I need it to where it trims everything before the first '_'

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 5):

Use `stuff()` and `charindex()`:

```
select stuff(document, 1, charindex('_', document) - 1, '')
```